# Spring MVC :Multi language support

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring MVC. In my app a user should be able to post comments/text in multiple language (english, japneese,chineese,polish etc). These post will be stored in DB also. So how can i enable multi language support in my UI side and server side

What are the things i need to do. I seen some internationalization example but my confusion is that it use properties file to store meaning of each word. and that is the issue that how can i store each and every words. Is it something i need? An example will be good enough

Comment: Multi language support doesn't involve translating user content, just the content provided by the app. If a user comments in Polish, then all other users will see the comment in Polish, no matter what language they have chosen.

Comment: so if have set UTF-8 encoding and storing whatever language user type in database . will i get the same thing when i will display it in web page without doing any extra effort?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to do what the examples tell you.  You don't have to store the meaning, but you do have to have one property for every string you want to internationalize in the UI.

You need to realize that the Spring I18N examples only deal with UI display in different languages.  Multi-language in the database will require a separate effort.

You need a lot more expertise than you'll get from an example here or on the web.

Comment: yah we can manage UI part because that will be in fixed amount. So that is not big issue. Problem start how to manage the post, comments?if someone write polish it should should show polish on the page......but how :(

Comment: Their browser locale will have to be set to Polish.  You'll have to encode content appropriately.  It's not trivial.  You need to know Unicode and encoding backwards and forwards.

Answer (score 0):

Most websites have Language link (i.e. **en** for English, **fr** for French, etc.).  Therefore, you sort out the differing languages depending on the language link that the user has chosen.

Another way, would be to have some sort of auto-detection, so if the user enters some common words that belong specifically to a certain language, then you can highlight the auto selected language and also give the user the option to override the auto-detection and manually select the language.  A good example of this is Google's [translate website](http://translate.google.com).

Also, make sure that every component from front-end to back-end is set for UTF-8 encoding.  That is, your web/application server (e.g. Tomcat), your application framework (e.g. Spring) and your database including your IDE setting and that all files including jsp/html files are saved as UTF-8 encoding and have UTF-8 declared (such as having... `<%@ page language="java" session="false" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"%>` and `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >` in your jsp/html files).

Answer (score 0):

For Spring l18n with database usage extend AbstractMessageSource. Java conifg:

```
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource(){
        DataBaseMessageSource source = new DatabaseMessageSource();

        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
        SessionLocaleResolver resolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH); //setup default locale
       return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("lang"); //will change current user locale when hit url with ?lang
        registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    }
```

and

```
public class DatabaseMessageBandle extends AbstractMessageSource {

@Autowired
private FooRepository fooRepo;


@Override
protected MessageFormat resolveCode(String code, Locale locale) {
    String message = getMessage(code, locale);

    MessageFormat messageFormat = createMessageFormat(message, locale);

    return messageFormat;
}

@Override
protected String resolveCodeWithoutArguments(String code, Locale locale) {
    return getMessage(code, locale);
}

private String getMessage(String code, Locale locale) {
   String message = fooRepo.getMeesageByCodeAndLocale(code, locale); //better not do this 
    return message;
}

}
```

and if you need to get current locale in controller:

```
@RequestMapping
public String index(Locale locale) {  //you will have it
//or use LocaleContextHolder.getLocale, and it will return current thread locale

return "index";
}
```